# How to multiply values of same keys in hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

Given two hashes `hash1` and `hash2`, which may be of different size, I need to multiply the values of any recurrence of a key; the extra key-value pairs should not be taken into account.

Consider for instance the example below:

```
hash1 = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }
hash2 = { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

Common keys are `:a` and `:b` (`:c` should not be considered). What can I do to select only `:a` and `:b` and return `2 * 3` (for `:a`) and `3 * 4` (for `:b`), that is array `[6, 12]`?

Comment: Are the common keys in the two hashes the same (relative) order in the two hashes? If not, it is not clear how the values are supposed to be ordered in your expected array. How do you know that it is `[6, 12]` and not `[12, 6]`?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash1.map { |k, v| v * hash2[k] if hash2.key? k }.compact
```

Comment: This is cleaner and **compact** than my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
common_keys = hash1.keys & hash2.keys
multiply = []
common_keys.each do |key|
  multiply << hash1[key] * hash2[key]
end
puts multiply
```

Comment: That does not give what the OP asked.

Comment: Thanks @sawa. Edited.